# Datalist Compatibility for all browsers

Tags: visualforce

I am creating a datalist on vf page.This datalist is compatible for all browsers but it’s not working on ios.so can we make a datalist or something else which functionality should be same like datalist by some other way using javascript and visualforce which will be compatible for all browsers ? please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use a native SF component so you don't have to worry about compatibility (as long as you only support what Salesforce supports).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm is pretty easy to use.